# best way to create unique addressID

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a unique address_id in my customers table which has 4000 entries already. I want to have multiple shipping addresses in another table for those customers that have the need for it.

I think I could use the customer_id and add a leading digit to it to make it unique. How is this normally done and when adding a new customer how does it know to add the leading digit to the customer_id to populate the address_id?

```
customer_id int 11 autonumber
address_id int 11
other fields
```

Comment: The `customers` table would have an autoincrement, and the `addresses` table would have an autoincrement. Your addresses table would have a `customer_id` field that links them to the customer.

Comment: ah... so set it up the same as my orders table which has an auto increment order# and customer_id for each customer.  Thanks!